# HP mute button LED not working

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, keyboard, led

All of a sudden my mute LED stopped working. It was working fine for a while, but then out of the blue, it just stopped. At the same time, I also had an audio driver issue. So, I reinstalled the drivers, restarted and still has the same issue (the driver worked but the led didn't). I browsed the HP forums and their only fix is updating the drivers. What could be the potential problem, and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its possible that the led blew, or that the controlling circuit for that led has a fault; it may or may not be software related.

Comment: I don't think that's the case since it works on Linux just not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

What driver did you reinstall?

If it works fine on Linux, but it can't work on Windows, it is usually a combination key driver problem on the keyboard. We need to download the key combination driver for the corresponding machine model on the HP official website.